# Syntax error in urls.py . How to debug it?

Tags: python, django

The error is this

"\t(r'ajax/lookup/^$','ajaxlookup',name='ajax_lookup'),\n"))

I have installed geonode and in that I have put ajax_select to do autocomplete. But my URLs.py is giving an error

My urls.py looks like this

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, url

js_info_dict = {
    'packages': ('geonode.maps',),
}

    urlpatterns = patterns('geonode.maps.views',
        (r'^$', 'maps'),
        url(r'^new$', 'newmap', name="map_new"),
        (r'^(?P<mapid>\d+)$', 'map_controller'),
        (r'^(?P<mapid>\d+)/view$', 'view'),
        (r'^(?P<mapid>\d+)/download/$', 'map_download'),
        (r'^check/$', 'check_download'),
        (r'^embed/$', 'embed'),
        (r'^(?P<mapid>\d+)/embed$', 'embed'),
        (r'^(?P<mapid>\d+)/data$', 'mapJSON'),
        url(r'^search/?$', 'maps_search_page', name='maps_search'),
        url(r'^search/api/?$', 'maps_search', name='maps_search_api'),
        url(r'^(?P<mapid>\d+)/ajax-permissions$', 'ajax_map_permissions', name='ajax_map_permissions'),
        url(r'^change-poc/(?P<ids>\w+)$', 'change_poc', name="change_poc"),
        url(r'^search/$', 'maps_search', name='maps_search'),

    )

    urlpatterns += patterns('geonode.ajax_select.views',
        (r'ajax/lookup/^$','ajaxlookup',name='ajax_lookup'),
    )
```

My templates in the html file looks like this

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Ext.onReady(function(){
           {% autoescape off %}

            var searchTable = new GeoNode.MapSearchTable({
                renderTo: 'search_results',
                trackSelection: true,
                permalinkURL: '{% url ajax_lookup %}',
                searchURL: '{% url ajax_lookup %}',
                searchParams: {{init_search}}
            });
        {% endautoescape %}
    });

</script>
```

And my ajax_lookup looks like this

Answer (score 2):

Tuples do not support keyword arguments. Convert the entry to a `url()` call.

Comment: Can you give us the whole syntax

Comment: `url(r'ajax/lookup/^$','ajaxlookup',name='ajax_lookup'),`

Comment: After doing that I got an error saying this . 

Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering:

Comment: That doesn't mean my answer is wrong, that just means that you have another problem.

Comment: That might be because your regex makes little sense. Try `r'^ajax/lookup$'` instead?

Comment: If my urls.py looks like that , what change should I do in template forms?

Comment: We don't know. What are you doing now?

Comment: I am trying to do an autocomplete feature in geonode using Ajax_select

Answer (score 0):

it should be:

```
urlpatterns += patterns('geonode.ajax_select.views',
        (r'^ajax/lookup/$','ajaxlookup',name='ajax_lookup'),
    )
```

the "^" was at the end :)

Comment: While this is true, that will cause a logic error, not a syntax error.

Comment: combine the two answers -- like I said in my comment at Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams's answer below :)

Comment: How does the error look like? Is it "Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering" ?

Comment: No, the "^" was pointing at the '=' sign after the word 'name'. See Ignacio's answer.

Comment: it probable doesn't like the $ an the end. Maybe the url pattern name is beeing used wrong in the template? How does it look the template? More context :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102709/how-do-i-write-the-template-form-in-django-if-my-views-py-looks-like-this

Comment: Any help will be really appreciated as I am terribly confused where to go from there . I want to do an autocomplete jquery thus I used ajax_select .