# How do I write the template form in Django if my views.py looks like this?

Tags: jquery, django

```
def ajax_lookup(request,channel):
```

This is one of my views.I am using this to do autocomplete

This is the js for it . And I am getting  an obvious error of lesser no. of attributes being sent as I am sending 1 in place of 2. How do I send the second argument ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Ext.onReady(function(){
   {% autoescape off %}

    var searchTable = new GeoNode.MapSearchTable({
        renderTo: 'search_results',
        trackSelection: true,
        permalinkURL: '{% url ajax_lookup %}',
        searchURL: '{% url ajax_lookup %}',
        searchParams: {{init_search}}
    });


    {% endautoescape %}
});
</script>
```

Comment: `url` looks at the urlconf, not the view.

Answer (score 0):

Might this fix it?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Ext.onReady(function(){
   {% autoescape off %}

    var searchTable = new GeoNode.MapSearchTable({
        renderTo: 'search_results',
        trackSelection: true,
        permalinkURL: '{% url views.ajax_lookup channel.id %}',
        searchURL: '{% url views.ajax_lookup channel.id %}',
        searchParams: {{init_search}}
    });


    {% endautoescape %}
});
</script>
```