# Why I get a this error that invalid syntax (urls.py, line 34)

Tags: django, django-urls, django-generic-views

my url.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url 
import os.path
from crm.views import *

(r'^workDailyRecord/(?P<mode_name>\w+/)?$', workDailyRecord),
(r'^user/search/$', searchUser),
#   (r'^tset/$', mainPage),
#   (r'^ptpt/$', mainPage),
    (r'^tptp/$', TodayLogView.as_view(), name='archive_today'), #34 Line
)
```

***Why?*** I recive that?? Why? Please help me!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Syntax error in urls.py . How to debug it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102407/syntax-error-in-urls-py-how-to-debug-it)

Comment: please write "url" in the begining of line no. 34, as you are using the named urls now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `url` in this order of parameters:

```
...
url(r'^tptp/$', TodayLogView.as_view(), name='archive_today'),
...
```

Excerpt from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/urls/#url):

> You can use the url() function, instead of a tuple, as an argument to
>   patterns(). This is convenient if you want to specify a name without
>   the optional extra arguments dictionary.